# How do I disable the cursorline in vim for the nerdtree plugin?

Tags: vim

I can disable the cursorline in the nerdtree plugin by the following command

```
:set nocursorline
```

but how do I do it in my .vimrc file?

Comment: Please ask at https://vi.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `let NERDTreeHighlightCursorline=0`. More details see NERDTree [doc](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERDTree.txt).
By the way, before asking question, you should check the manual first.

Comment: put this into your `.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but you can do this the exact same way.

```
set nocursorline
```